# DataTable with Paginate Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

How we can create DataTable from Firestore collection and keep only one column on the top of ListView ?, with below code column is present for each row, also if the collection contain 1000 docs the column should not be hidden when user scoll

Below is my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FirestoreQueryBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
      pageSize: 5,
      query: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users'),
      builder: (context, snapshot, _) {
        return ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemCount: snapshot.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            if (snapshot.hasMore && index + 1 == snapshot.docs.length) {
              snapshot.fetchMore();
            }
            final user = snapshot.docs[index].data();
            return DataTable(
              columns: const <DataColumn>[
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('User Name'),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('User email'),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('User Id'),
                ),
              ],
              rows: [
                DataRow(
                  cells: [
                    DataCell(
                      Text(user['name']),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Text(user['email']),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Text(user['id']),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

NOTE : I'm using flutterfire_ui to paginate collection

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. You are not required to use `ListView` while using `DataTable` class because it also required `List<Widget>`.
2. You can use [PaginatedDataTable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PaginatedDataTable-class.html) class for this purpose. Instead of using `DataTable` just use `PaginatedDataTable`

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FirestoreQueryBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
      pageSize: 5,
      query: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users'),
      builder: (context, snapshot, _) {
            return PaginatedDataTable(
              columns: const <DataColumn>[
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('User Name'),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('User email'),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('User Id'),
                ),
              ],
               source: MyData(snapshot.docs),
                onPageChanged: snapshot.fetchMore,  
            );
          },
    );
  }
}

// The "soruce" of the table
class MyData extends DataTableSource {
  MyData(this._data);
final List<dynamic> _data;
  

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;
  @override
  int get rowCount => _data.length;
  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].data()['name'])),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].data()["email"])),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].data()["id"])),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Karim for the quick answer, but I want to use infinite scroll  in the same page, no need to click on next page / previous page 
and please update your example to make it compile (source: MyData(snapshot.docs), onPageChanged: (index) => snapshot.fetchMore);)

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to achieve this using  data_table_2 package

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 30.0,
            icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.search),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
        title: const Text('DataTable2 Firebase'),
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 60,
            child: DataTable2(
              columns: const <DataColumn>[
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('name'),
                ),
                DataColumn(label: Text('age'), numeric: true),
                DataColumn(label: Text('score'), numeric: true),
              ],
              rows: const [],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
              child: FirestoreQueryBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                pageSize: 10,
                query: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users'),
                builder: (context, snapshot, _) {
                  if (snapshot.hasMore) {
                    snapshot.fetchMore();
                  }
                  return DataTable2(
                    columnSpacing: 0,
                    horizontalMargin: 12,
                    bottomMargin: 10,
                    minWidth: 50,
                    headingRowHeight: 0,
                    columns: const <DataColumn>[
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Text(''),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(label: Text(''), numeric: true),
                      DataColumn(label: Text(''), numeric: true),
                    ],
                    rows: snapshot.docs
                        .map((e) => DataRow(cells: [
                              DataCell(
                                Text(
                                  e.data()['name'],
                                ),
                              ),
                              DataCell(
                                Text(
                                  e.data()['age'].toString(),
                                ),
                              ),
                              DataCell(
                                Text(
                                  e.data()['score'].toString(),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ]))
                        .toList(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 50,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```